# Как сделать ожидание нажатий на формы для получения данных

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

Всем привет. Пишу программу для работы с картой и использую GMAP. Во время работы я хотел реализовать создание полигона между 2 маркерами на карте как на рисунке 1.
[image: 1]. И хотел реализовать такой функционал чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выходило сообщение с просьбой нажать на маркеры( Там через событие OnMarkerClick Будут получены координаты маркеров для постройки полигона) и когда будут получены координаты построиться полигон(прямая линия между ними). Но я не знаю как сделать ожидание ввода этих нажатий. Ивент на нажатие мышью`

```
private void gMapControl1_OnMarkerClick(GMapMarker item, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                _markerBufItemOne = item;
            }
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && CreateEdge == true)
            {
                _markerBufItemTwo = item;
            }

        }//Ивент на создание полигона 
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateEdge = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Выберете на карте нужные точки 1-Левой кнопкой мыши 2-Правой кнопкой мыши", "Информация", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            GMapOverlay routes = new GMapOverlay("routes");
            List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>
            {
                new PointLatLng(55.792318, 49.124549),
                new PointLatLng(55.792318, 49.122549)
            };`
```

Comment: зачем делать ожидание воода? Задача похожа на машину состояний. Вам надо на форме иметь состояния, и в зависимости от них реагировать на клики.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю как реализовать машину состояний.